# Reading the Json value

Tags: c#, json

I am using below code to get the value of json

```
using static ScriptParser.JsonData;

namespace ScriptParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var url = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Subusam/demojson/db";
            //var ScriptDetails = _download_serialized_json_data<Rootobject>(url);

           // Console.WriteLine(ScriptDetails);
            var ScriptDetails = _download_serialized_json_data<Rootobject>(url);
            Console.WriteLine(ScriptDetails);
        }

    }
}
```

To deserialize the json below code is used

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ScriptParser
{
    class JsonData
    {
        public static JasonRaw _download_serialized_json_data<JasonRaw>(string url) where JasonRaw : new()
        {
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {
                var json_data = string.Empty;
                // attempt to download JSON data as a string
                try
                {
                    json_data = w.DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
                // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JasonRaw>(json_data) : new JasonRaw();
            }
        }

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public execution[] execution { get; set; }
            public scenarios scenarios { get; set; }

        }

        public class scenarios
        {
            public threadGroup threadGroup { get; set; }
        }

        public class threadGroup
        {
            public request[] requests { get; set; }
        }

       public class request
        {
            public string label { get; set; }
            public string method { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
        }

        public class execution
        {
            public int concurrency { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hold-for")]
            public string holdfor { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ramp-up")]
            public string rampup { get; set; }
            public string scenario { get; set; }
        }     

    }
}
```

and the Json file look like

```
{
        "execution": [{
            "concurrency": 10,
            "hold-for": "60s",
            "ramp-up": "60s",
            "scenario": "Thread Group"
        }],
        "scenarios": {
            "Thread Group": {
                "data-sources": [{}],
                "requests": [{
                    "headers": {
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        "id": "loadtest",
                        "user-id": "5"
                    },
                    "label": "GET abc",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "url": "http://abc.abc.com/abc-abc-service-api/v1/abc/${id}?debug=false"
                }]
                }
            }
    }
```

Now I want to extract the values like "method", "url" ,"concurrency","hold-for", "ramp-up".Need assistance in my code as I am facing issue to fetch the values.
While runing this code I am not getting the values of "method" and "url".
I have attached the snap of value I am getting while run the code

[image]

Comment: have you debugged? Is '!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data)' coming out true?

Comment: Also please provide compiling code. You deserialize `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JasonRaw>` where it should be by what you gave 'Rootobject'

Comment: it works!  thanks @GiladGreen

Comment: So much code for such a small task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the names of the properties in the classes don't match those in the JSON. use the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) attribute to specify.

For instance for `execution` class:

```
public class execution
{
    public int concurrency { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("hold-for")]
    public string holdfor { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ramp-up")]
    public string rampup { get; set; }
    public string scenario { get; set; }
}
```

and for `scenarios` do:

```
public class scenarios
{
    [JsonProperty("Thread Group")]
    public threadGroup threadGroup { get; set; }
}
```